# Clone entire disk to image using clonezilla and keep bootloader(s)

Tags: backup, disk-image, clonezilla

I have hardware issues with my notebook, so I'm sending it in tomorrow and need to backup the disk. Because I have multiple OSes installed it would be very important for me to preserve the bootloaders installed on the disk.
My question is, if the bootloaders will survive the backup when I use clonezilla's disk to image option.
OSes are Windows in EFI mode and ubuntu booted through grub also in EFI mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clonezilla disk image by default images the partition table(s), bootloaders, and all types of partitions. I believe it makes an assumption that the MBR or primary GPT and any boot loader that is not located in its own partition is located within the first 1 MiB on the disk. This is the case by default with all of the disk tools that I've ever heard of or used in both Linux and MS, including software raid.

I also believe it makes special effort to copy the backup GPT if it exists from the end of the disk.

All partitions are also imaged. If it doesn't understand the partition it just copies the whole thing byte for byte.

I'm not sure what options it gives if there is no MBR or GPT, like in the case of ZFS on bare disks or simply corrupt partition tables. I assume there is an option, probably in the advanced section to simply copy the whole disk byte for byte.