# Dualboot only finds Windows after Clonezilla restore

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, clonezilla, bootrepair

so some facts:

- Had a dualboot installed on my laptop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.
- I got a new SSD for my laptop, increasing the internal disk space size from 512GB to 2TB.
- As there is only a single SSD slot in my laptop I had to replace the SSD.
- I used clonezilla to clone the whole 512GB SSD to an image on a external storage.
- I replaced the 512GB with the 2TB SSD
- With clonezilla I cloned back the image from the external storage to the 2TB SSD.
- When booting now the internal SSD, it directly starts Windows. No different boot options anymore.
- **The problem: The Ubuntu partition seems to be there, however I can't choose to boot from it.**
- I used an Ubuntu live and tried 'boot-repair' (for which I have the paste bin ), however, it doesn't even show the 'repair' button.

Now I am a bit stuck how I should continue. In my understanding it just doesn't find the 'old' grub section to boot from. Do you have any idea how to fix these issues and re-enable booting into Ubuntu as well as Windows?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you load `msconfig` and go to the Boot tab, are there 2 entries?

Comment: No, there is just the Windows 10 entry

Comment: On your original installation - did you use GRUB or the Microsoft Boot manager to select the boot target?

Comment: I used GRUB there

Comment: This is the paste from boot-repair https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Fwps3w36c2/

Comment: Really any support would be highly appreciated here. To me it seems like there is a clear solution to that. I just don't know what exactly needs to be done. I also added a bounty for this question now.

Comment: You should really use a pastebin that doesn't require people to log in or just add the paste as code block in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I've found some explanation of what might have cause your problem:

[Clone entire disk to image using clonezilla and keep bootloader(s)](https://superuser.com/questions/875379/clone-entire-disk-to-image-using-clonezilla-and-keep-bootloaders/875387#875387)

And here's a guide to restore the MBR so you can choose the OS once again, you will need a live USB

https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 0):

You could try repairing the boot by opening an elevated Command Prompt in Windows and running

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

I found this from https://windowsreport.com/fix-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu/